# Change text style on a table

Tags: tables, longtable

I have this table:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\keepXColumns
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{ >{\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}%
  {| >{\hsize=1.1\hsize\columncolor{blue!10}}X|
  >{\hsize=0.55\hsize}X|
  >{\hsize=1.25\hsize\rule{0pt}{4ex}}X <{\mbox{}\rule[-2.5ex]{0pt}{0pt}}|
  >{\hsize=1.1\hsize}X|}
  \hline
  \rowcolor{gray!50}\textbf{a} & \textbf{b} & \textbf{c} & \textbf{d} \\%
  \hline
  \endfirsthead
  \hline
  \endhead
  \textbf{Bla bla bla}\par
  \emph{jjjjj}
                               & r & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ut elit ac ipsum placerat scelerisque eget id justo. Ut cursus viverra neque, in porta justo facilisis sit amet. Donec vitae libero a diam lobortis ultrices. Vestibulum metus urna, pharetra et cursus quis, eleifend ut dui. Phasellus pellentesque, quam et hendrerit. & d \\
  \cline{2-4}
                               & r & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ut elit ac ipsum placerat scelerisque eget id justo. hendrerit. & k
  \\
  \cline{2-4}
                               & g & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ut elit ac ipsum placerat scelerisque eget id justo. Ut cursus viverra neque, in porta justo facilisis sit amet. Donec vitae libero a diam lobortis ultrices. Vestibulum metus urna, pharetra et cursus quis, eleifend ut dui. Phasellus pellentesque, quam et hendrerit. & p
  \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

I want to set a smaller text size because the table is a long table and I'm trying to resize the table a little. I want accomplish this without modify the text size of the whole document. Is it possible?

Comment: you could put squarebraces around the `tabularx` environment, and put in `\tiny` or `\small` in front of it. So you would have `{\tiny
\begin{tabularx}…\end{tabularx}}. In most cases though, you should probably rethink how you present your table.

Comment: Why don't you typeset the table in `landscape` mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me elaborate and extend @David answer:

- for smaller fonts only in (long) table: `{\small\begin{tabularx} ... \end{tabularx}}`
- don't exaggerate
  in reduction of font size, to small fonts is difficult to read
- slightly< more space cor cells content can be achieved with reduction of `tabcolsep`, for example from default `6pt` to `3pt` (see MWE below)
- reduce additional vertical spaces in cells

With mentioned measures and also some simplification of your code see, Your MWE become:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=30mm,]{geometry}% <-- added
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\keepXColumns
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{ >{\arraybackslash}m{#1}<{\smallskip}}% <-- changed
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

{\small%\footnotesize                   %  don't use font size below \footnoteseze
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}         % <-- added
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}   % <-- added
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}    % <-- added
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}%
  {|>{\hsize=1.10\hsize\columncolor{blue!10}}X|
    >{\hsize=0.55\hsize}X|
    >{\hsize=1.25\hsize}X|              % <-- changed
    >{\hsize=1.10\hsize}X|}
    \hline
\rowcolor{gray!50}\textbf{a} & \textbf{b} & \textbf{c} & \textbf{d} \\%
    \hline
\endfirsthead
    \hline                              % <-- changed
\rowcolor{gray!50}\textbf{a} & \textbf{b} & \textbf{c} & \textbf{d} \\%
    \hline
\endhead
    \hline                              % <-- added
\endfoot
\textbf{Bla bla bla}\par
  \emph{jjjjj}
    &   r   &   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ut elit ac ipsum placerat scelerisque eget id justo. Ut cursus viverra neque, in porta justo facilisis sit amet. Donec vitae libero a diam lobortis ultrices. Vestibulum metus urna, pharetra et cursus quis, eleifend ut dui. Phasellus pellentesque, quam et hendrerit. 
                &   d   \\  \cline{2-4}
   &    r   &   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ut elit ac ipsum placerat scelerisque eget id justo. hendrerit. 
                &   k   \\  \cline{2-4}
    &    g   &   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ut elit ac ipsum placerat scelerisque eget id justo. Ut cursus viverra neque, in porta justo facilisis sit amet. Donec vitae libero a diam lobortis ultrices. Vestibulum metus urna, pharetra et cursus quis, eleifend ut dui. Phasellus pellentesque, quam et hendrerit. 
                &   p   \\
\end{tabularx}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Further improvement of your table enables:

- use macro `RaggedRight` from packages  `ragged2e` in column definition
- use features of package `microtype`, its influence is noticeable with font size `footnotesize`:

[image]

For above table the MWE preamble and table column definitions are:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=30mm,]{geometry}% <-- added
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\keepXColumns
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{ >{\arraybackslash}m{#1}<{\smallskip}}% <-- changed
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{ragged2e}                   % <-- now used
\usepackage{microtype}                  % <-- added

\begin{document}

{\footnotesize
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}         % <-- added
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}   % <-- added
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}    % <-- added
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}%
  {|>{\hsize=1.10\hsize\columncolor{blue!10}}X|
    >{\hsize=0.55\hsize\RaggedRight}X|
    >{\hsize=1.25\hsize\RaggedRight}X|              % <-- changed
    >{\hsize=1.10\hsize\RaggedRight}X|}
% further is the same as in the above MWE
```

Since it is not clear, what you mean with text style, in above examples I only consider changes of font size. Also is possible to change fonts family. With selection `\sffamily`, i.e. by

```
{\footnotesize\sffamily
```

which is narrowed than used default \rmamily` fonts the text in cells become even more compact:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

yeah go with like `\scriptsize` `\tiny` `\footnotesize` etc..

Comment: Although this is on the right track, the main idea of TeX.SX is explain what is going on and to give details. Do you want to expand you answer to show how your suggestion works for the OPs example?